# How to use define_method inside initialize()

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Trying to use `define_method` inside `initialize` but getting undefined_method `define_method`. What am I doing wrong?

```
class C
  def initialize(n)    
    define_method ("#{n}") { puts "some method #{n}" }    
  end
end

C.new("abc") #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `define_method' for #<C:0x2efae80>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Nothing specific, trying to see how I can dynamically define a method using `define_method`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Do as below :

```
class C
  def initialize(n)    
    self.class.send(:define_method,n) { puts "some method #{n}" }    
  end
end

ob = C.new("abc")
ob.abc
# >> some method abc
```

[`Module#define_method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method) is a *private method* and also a *class* method.Your one didn't work,as you tried to call it on the instance of `C`.You have to call it on `C`,using `#send` in your case.

Comment: It works. Could you explain why my earlier version is incorrect?

Comment: @Bala: Note that `o = C.new('pancakes')` will leave you with `ob.abc`, `ob.pancakes`, `o.abc`, and `o.pancakes` as valid method calls. Is everyone sure that this is the intent?

Comment: @muistooshort: Interesting comment. Although there was no intent, now I am thinking how to make it object specific (singleton).

Comment: `Your one didn't work,as you tried to call it on the instance of C` ---> it is not immediately clear to me why a private method cannot be called in an instance of `c`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 47):

I suspect that you're looking for [`define_singleton_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method):

> **define_singleton_method(symbol, method) → new_method**
>   **define_singleton_method(symbol) { block } → proc**
>
> Defines a singleton method in the receiver. The *method* parameter can be a `Proc`, a `Method` or an `UnboundMethod` object. If a block is specified, it is used as the method body.

If you use [`define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-define_method) on `self.class`, you'll create the new method as an instance method on the whole class so it will be available as a method on all instances of the class.

You'd use `define_singleton_method` like this:

```
class C
  def initialize(s)    
    define_singleton_method(s) { puts "some method #{s}" }    
  end
end
```

And then:

```
a = C.new('a')
b = C.new('b')
a.a # puts 'some method a'
a.b # NoMethodError
b.a # NoMethodError
b.b # puts 'some method b'
```

If your `initialize` did:

```
self.class.send(:define_method,n) { puts "some method #{n}" }
```

then you'd get:

```
a.a # puts 'some method a'
a.b # puts 'some method b'
b.a # puts 'some method a'
b.b # puts 'some method b'
```

and that's probably not what you're looking for. Creating a new instance and having the entire class change as a result is rather odd.

Comment: I had a follow up question to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56100281/when-to-use-define-singleton-method-v-define-method

Comment: Great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. Just point to the class with `self.class`, don't even need to use `:send`:

```
class C
  def initialize(n)    
    self.class.define_method ("#{n}") { puts "some method #{n}" }    
  end
end
ob = C.new('new_method')
ob2 = C.new('new_method2')
# Here ob and ob2 will have access to new_method and new_method2 methods
```

You can also use it with `:method_missing` to teach your class new methods like this:

```
class Apprentice
  def method_missing(new_method)
    puts "I don't know this method... let me learn it :)"
    self.class.define_method(new_method) do
      return "This is a method I already learned from you: #{new_method}"
    end
  end
end
ap = Apprentice.new
ap.read
=> "I don't know this method... let me learn it :)"
ap.read
=> "This is a method I already learned from you: read"
```